# Azure App Service Mobile App .Net Backend issue while creating Table Controller

Tags: .net, cordova, azure

I have created a Azure App Service Mobile App backend using .Net and downloaded the service application. It have built it and able to publish back to Azure and it is working fine by creating TodoList table.

But when I add a new Data Object and Table Controller and publish back to Azure the service gives me "Internal Server Error 500" when i run my client application. The service is published successfully. Am using a Cordova client app and running using Google Android Emulator from VS 2015.

Entity:

```
public class Article : EntityData
{
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public byte[] ArticleImage { get; set; }
}
```

Did any body come across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing two things here - to generate Data migration scripts and delete data from _MigrationHistory table.